# Cannot import bacpac from blob storage

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql

I'm unable to import a data tier application (BACPAC) via SSMS from Azure storage on my PC.

It works with the same account on multiple other PCs, the only difference is that that runs an older version of SSMS (I am on version 19) but I can't see why that would matter. It works when importing a downloaded BACPAC file from the local disk.

The error occurs after selecting the Blob container and clicking OK:

```
The remote name could not be resolved: 'serverremoved.core.windows.net' (System)
```

I have tried signing out and in, flushing DNS, etc. As noted it works under the same Azure account on multiple other systems.

SSMS is up to date at v19.1.56.0 and was installed yesterday after removing v18 due to a higher DB version requirement.